# is there a way to highlight cell/s in a TCalendar?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I know there's a way to highlight a cell in a `TStringGrid`. I could use that, but inputting the dates and days and months would be a big issue unless you know how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is easy if you only make a small modification to the control's source code. Specifically, we need to add a small amount of code to its `DrawCell` method.

Initially, this is

```
procedure TCalendar.DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState);
var
  TheText: string;
begin
  TheText := CellText[ACol, ARow];
  with ARect, Canvas do
    TextRect(ARect, Left + (Right - Left - TextWidth(TheText)) div 2,
      Top + (Bottom - Top - TextHeight(TheText)) div 2, TheText);
end;
```

Change this to:

```
procedure TCalendar.DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState);
var
  TheText: string;
  i: Integer;
  Day: Integer;
begin
  TheText := CellText[ACol, ARow];
  with ARect, Canvas do
  begin
    Font.Style := [];
    for i := Low(HighlightDates) to High(HighlightDates) do
      if TryStrToInt(TheText, Day) then
        if SameDate(HighlightDates[i], EncodeDate(Year, Month, Day)) then
        begin
          Font.Style := [fsBold];
          Break;
        end;
    TextRect(ARect, Left + (Right - Left - TextWidth(TheText)) div 2,
      Top + (Bottom - Top - TextHeight(TheText)) div 2, TheText);
  end;
end;
```

The easiest way to quickly try this is to use an interposer class:

```
type
  TCalendar = class(Vcl.Samples.Calendar.TCalendar)
    procedure DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
```

Now you only need to supply an array of dates to highlight:

```
var
  HighlightDates: TArray<TDate>;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(HighlightDates, 3);
  HighlightDates[0] := EncodeDate(2020, 07, 10);
  HighlightDates[1] := EncodeDate(2020, 07, 20);
  HighlightDates[2] := EncodeDate(2020, 08, 10);
end;
```

or, in new Delphi versions (XE7 and later),

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HighlightDates :=
    [
      EncodeDate(2020, 07, 10),
      EncodeDate(2020, 07, 20),
      EncodeDate(2020, 08, 10)
    ];
end;
```

Don't forget to add `DateUtils` to the `uses` clause.

[image: Screenshot of a TCalendar control with two dates selected: 2020-07-10 and 2020-07-20.]

(I apologise for the Swedish day names.)

Needless to say, you can paint highlighted cells in any way you like; making the font bold is only one possibility. If instead you want to highlight a cell by drawing a benzene ring in its top-right corner, that's fine too.

You will want to create a new control with the new code. In this, the date array would be a member. It could have an associated property with a setter that also invalidates the control. In addition, you could add public `HighlightDate(const ADate: TDate)` and `StopHighlightDate(const ADate: TDate)` procedures that add and remove dates from this array (and invalidate the control).

## Update

On request (see comments), here is how to change the background colour of highlighted cells:

```
{ TCalendar }

procedure TCalendar.DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect;
  AState: TGridDrawState);
var
  TheText: string;
  i: Integer;
  Day: Integer;
  OldColor: TColor;
begin
  TheText := CellText[ACol, ARow];
  with ARect, Canvas do
  begin
    OldColor := Brush.Color;
    for i := Low(HighlightDates) to High(HighlightDates) do
      if TryStrToInt(TheText, Day) then
        if SameDate(HighlightDates[i], EncodeDate(Year, Month, Day)) then
        begin
          Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
          FillRect(ARect);
          Break;
        end;
    TextRect(ARect, Left + (Right - Left - TextWidth(TheText)) div 2,
      Top + (Bottom - Top - TextHeight(TheText)) div 2, TheText);
    Brush.Color := OldColor;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Screenshot of calendar with cells highlighted using a different cell background colour.]

Comment: You can always open the file manually. On my system, it is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\source\vcl`. On your system, the version number is certainly different.

Comment: hey i have an issue normally how I would access the calendar class by right-clicking and then clicking find declaration but when I do that it says unable to locate calendar.pas  i actally want to highlight the text and change the cell color to red from a database i actually found a question like that but it was on mobile and a different version of Delphi  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632022/how-to-change-cell-color-in-a-tcalendar-component-in-delphi)  im sorry i hav no idea on how to use an  interposer class: i actually added it under type and the 'Vcl.Samples.'GotHighlighted

Comment: How would i further color the cell red

Comment: Set `Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed` and use `TCanvas.FillRect` to fill the cell. Do this before you draw the text (otherwise you will hide your text with the red rectangle).

Comment: thanks you really helped me out any idea on how to change the cell color

Comment: hey when i copy and paste the code then try to save it delphi gives me and error and says  unable to create back up folder

Comment: Are you trying to save files to `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`? That's not possible. Windows won't let you access these protected folders. You should save your code in your personal folders, e.g. `C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents` in my case.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand This is exactly what I need,  but i don't understand it.. I will have to look at this for awhile unless someone has a quicker way to explain how I add this to my project..  I just want all days before TODAY() grey background and option to add other specific dates that will get grey background

Comment: I guess the one i need is for FMX.Calendar.pas  Because i dont see a draw option in the source for TCalendar.pas

Comment: Why use a `TStringGrid` for a calendar, instead of using [`TMonthCalendar`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TMonthCalendar)? It has an [`OnGetMonthBoldInfo`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCommonCalendar.OnGetMonthBoldInfo) event for highlighting dates