# How to change a cell's color in a TCalendar Component in Delphi2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

I need to change the colour of  a cell, in a `TCalendar` component on **`Delphi2010`.**

i want to input a date from a database(`adotable`)  and color that cell red
if that helps
i just im still a beginner so the simplest way is best

Comment: AFAIK, `TCalendar` does not directly support what you are asking for. Being a `TCustomGrid` descendant, you will likely have to derive a new class from `TCalendar` and override its virtual `DrawCell()` and/or `DrawCellBackground()` method.

Comment: That TCalendar component has been around since Delphi 1, and was an example of how to create components (that's why it's on the Samples palette page). You're much better off using the modern TCalendarView component, which will do what you're asking.

Comment: I outlined a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912484/is-there-a-way-to-highlight-cell-s-in-a-tcalendar. See the comments to the A.